# Link not showing up in div, but buttons do

Tags: css, html, button, hyperlink

I've been completely stuck for hours because of this problem. I have a div `container` which has a dynamically created fragment being inserted before a link `button`. However, the link doesn't show up. If I change the link to a `<input type="image">` or `<input type="button">`, then it will show up. The only way I can get the link to show up is to use absolute positioning, but that just breaks everything else.

This is the HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <a href="#" id="button" onClick="function();"></a>
</div>
```

and this is my CSS

```
#container {
    display: none;
    background: url(../img/background.png) top left repeat;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 55px;
    padding-bottom: 68px;
    width: 100%;
}

#button {
    margin: 10px;
    width: auto;
    height: 40px;
    background: url(../img/button.png) no-repeat bottom;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#button:hover {
    background: url(../img/buttonpress.png) no-repeat bottom;
}
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: please create a jsfiddle.

Comment: `#container { display: none }`?

Comment: @Pietu1998 Oh, should have just taken that out. That's just the initial style, but later on the Javascript changes it to block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try `display: block;` on link.

Comment: Oh... I'm an idiot. Thank you. But is there a reason that the link needs an explicit `display: block;` but the buttons don't?

Comment: Link is not block by default ;)

Comment: Are you using any kind of reset or boilertemplate css?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, CSS works with class. So, change this code:

```
<div id="container">
<a href="#" id="button" onClick="function();"></a>
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="container">
<a href="#" class="button" onClick="function();"></a>
</div>
```

It should work perfectly. 
EDIT: And remove the display:none also.

Comment: CSS works with Id and Class in the same way...you're giving a class to an element when you have multiple elements with same name/class.